# Conditional Statement Not Working With register_shutdown_function

Tags: php

I have class that builds different parts of a page (header, body, footer, etc), but when an error occurs, I want a different page to load. It works fine when an error exists, but both the page and the error page loads when there is no error. I tried to put a conditional in the header function but was told that was wrong. I'm still learning all of this, so your patience & understanding is greatly appreciated.

```
class template  {
        public function header($params) {
        ob_start();
        if ($this->currentTheme == '') {
            $this->loadTheme('default');
        }
        include($path.$this->themes[$this->currentTheme]['header']);
        }
       
        public function footer($params = null) {
        if ($this->currentTheme == '') {
            $this->loadTheme('default');
        }
        include($path.$this->themes[$this->currentTheme]['footer']);
        ob_end_flush();
        }
}

function my_error_handler()
        {
            $last_error = error_get_last();
            if ($last_error && $last_error['type']==E_ERROR || E_WARNING)
            {
              ob_end_clean();
              include(__DIR__ . "/../error/500.php");
              http_response_code(500);
            }       
        } 
register_shutdown_function('my_error_handler');
```

Comment: maybe you should post how you're calling these 3 functions..

Comment: I'm sure there are tons of questions already dealing with this kind of misunderstanding of `||`, but I can't think what to search for to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's [logical operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php), such as `||` take a boolean input, and give a boolean output. They don't have any special relationship with other operators such as `==`.

So this:

```
$last_error['type']==E_ERROR || E_WARNING
```

Is basically equivalent to this:

```
($last_error['type'] == E_ERROR)
||
(E_WARNING == true)
```

Which isn't what you want at all. You have to tell PHP what to compare `E_WARNING` against:

```
$last_error['type']==E_ERROR || $last_error['type']==E_WARNING
```

(As a side-note, you probably don't want to include Warnings here - the code will have continued after the Warning, and then run the shutdown handler at the end.)